# Typescript throws warning when using JSON objects with types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to get the properties of this JSON object inside a hook, using bracket notation. I'm sure this is working but Typescript keeps throwing that warning:

> Property 'github' does not exist on type 'PropertyValues'

useI18n.ts

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import i18n from 'i18n/index.json'

type JSONRaw = typeof i18n
type Name = keyof JSONRaw
type Language = keyof JSONRaw[Name]
type Selection = JSONRaw[Name]
type Property = Pick<Selection, Language>
type PropertyValues = Property[Language]

export default function useI18n (name: Name) {
  const { locale } = useRouter()

  const JSONFile: JSONRaw = i18n
  const wantedTextList = JSONFile[name]
  const localeLanguage = locale as Language
  const value = wantedTextList[localeLanguage]
  return value as PropertyValues
}
```

JSON

```
{
  "header": {
    "es-ar": {
      "text": "lorem ipsum 2."
    },
    "en-us": {
      "text": "lorem ipsum."
    }
  },
  "preferences": {
    "es-ar": {
      "text": "lorem ipsum 2"
    },
    "en-us": {
      "text": "lorem ipsum"
    }
  },
  
  "notavaible": {
    "es-ar": {
      "text": "lorem ipsum 2"
    },
    "en-us": {
      "text": "lorem ipsum"
    }
  },
  "postnav": {
    "en-us": {
      "github": "lorem ipsum 2",
      "edit": " lorem ipsum"
    },
    "es-ar": {
      "github": "lorem ipsum 2",
      "edit": "lorem ipsum"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the hook usage:

```
const { github, edit } = useI18n('postnav')
```

I expect to get the right types and scale it easy

Comment: You need generic, like `function useI18n <N extends Name> (name: N) { …`.

Comment: And last line `return value as PropertyValues`, don’t use `as` type assertion cus that’ll interfere will type inference, which is what you want. I believe `return value` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use generic parameter so that TS can infer the actual string literal value for `name` at the calling site.

And from my experiment, you also need to manually add a return type annotation to guide TS engine, otherwise it'll just infer the return type to be `{ text: string } | { github: string; edit: string }` which is correct but not specific enough.

Put together, the result is:

```
function useI18n<N extends Name>(name: N): JSONRaw[N][Language] {
  const { locale } = useRouter()
  const JSONFile: JSONRaw = i18n
  const wantedTextList = JSONFile[name]
  const localeLanguage = locale as Language
  const value = wantedTextList[localeLanguage]
  return value
}
```

See it in action in [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlgRgBxhgXhgbwFAxgIgAsBTAQwBNiAnfALi1zwOIgFpSb6cmn8piAHlDoEANiCrEAtvAAOEAK4yATADp8jPAF8ANJuZhWCiCO48C-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-Am4pUv45AAKjFxXBNxhrbu2hru-azzO3iB520C1G8rUnOC4wKQrYAROX6bo0GYKpeYDXneQgPtAGogf+47RnqeCSFAChUKgsGZqi2DYBusCYDAgJnM04ZPCc4beCAIDNBwSLUtWtYoB2i6yOsUCbPUi59tgAD0YlRAAegA-NgQA).